# How to change default application if it is missing in "other applications list"?

Tags: default-programs

I am currently trying to use texstudio as the default application for opening `*.tex` files, but I cannot change the default application associated with that file type.

I tried to change it by right-clicking on the .TEX file, then *Properties*, *Open with*, *Show other applications*. However, neither texmaker nor texstudio will appear in the programs list and oddly enough, there is no "add application" button anymore.

I tried to make an entry in my `/home/user/.local/share/applications/mimeapps/mimeapps.list` but nothing happened.

Is there no way to change the list of "other applications" or add an default application program manually?

Answer (score 8):

From what I've read [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/97683/change-default-text-editor-from-gedit-to-terminal-vim):

Create an `texstudio.desktop` file in `~/.local/share/applications/` with the following content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=TexStudio
Comment=Edit TEX files
Exec=texstudio %f
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=texstudio
Categories=TextEditor;
StartupNotify=true
MimeType=text/x-text;
```

On file browser, you can right click a `.tex` file for the context menu and choose `Open With` -> `Other Application`. Click on `Show other applications` and you should see this dialog with this:

[image: Choosing Texstudio]

You may have to change the `Exec` line, I am not sure if that would be the right application name.

Comment: I am trying to change my pptx opener. I have change `MimeType = application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation` but I am not sure what to write in Categories. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1):

What you need it to add this line to ~/.local/share/applications/defaults.list

```
text/x-tex=TEXOPENNER.desktop
```

which in your case is:

```
text/x-tex=texmaker.desktop
```

That should work.

:-)