# How can I change the default text editor from gedit to vim?

Tags: command-line, vim, default-programs

How can I change the default text editor from gedit to vim? When I click on a text file, I want it to open in vim under the terminal instead of gedit.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You don't say how you are clicking on this file, so I will explain a way to do it in Gnome from Nautilus.  It should work in other cases, I believe.

First, to get Vim (or any app) into the "open with other application" list, you need to create a .desktop file in `~/.local/share/applications` with a line in it like this:   `Exec=<command> %f`.  I just made one called vim.desktop with these lines:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Categories=;
Comment=Edit file in Vim
Exec=vim %f
GenericName=Text Editor
Hidden=false
Icon=vim
Name=Vim
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Version=1.0
```

This made "Vim" appear in the list of possible apps when I right-clicked in Nautilus, and opened the file as expected.

Let me know if there are any problems.

Comment: Just saw another answer when I posted this.  Looks like I wasted time, but perhaps it will help anyway, somehow.

Comment: Glad I could help.  Thanks for letting me know.  I learned something new, too, as I didn't know the answer, but decided it would be nice to know (and an exercise for my brain). :)

Comment: BTW, from a different thread, if you want to use vim automatically instead of gedit for all types of files. I think you could edit /etc/gnome/defaults.list, and replace gedit with vim, to use the vim desktop file.  I haven't tested this, though.

Comment: +1 Excellent tip. Not necessarely for vim, but in general to add new applications to Open with...

Comment: If you want vim to be the default choice for a file extension, not just another choice, add that extension to the `Categories=`.

Answer (score 23):

Open `defaults.list`

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/gnome/defaults.list`
```

Replace

```
text/plain=gedit.desktop
```

with

```
text/plain=gvim.desktop
```

Save and close.

For more details and screenshot check this answer: [How do I stop gedit from opening anything?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73203/how-do-i-stop-gedit-from-opening-anything/73210#73210)

Comment: Excellent answer! I'd like to add to this to open it with sudo vim /etc/gnome/defaults.list and then use the command %s_gedit_gvim_g

Comment: In general, it's better to set `EDITOR` and use `sudoedit` than to run the editor under `sudo`

Comment: Note that in Ubuntu 23.04 the correct path to the `defaults.list` file is `/usr/share/applications/defaults.list`. Modification of `/etc/gnome/defaults.list` does not have any effect. Also, if you want to replace the default Text Editor with Gedit and vice versa, their desktop entries are `org.gnome.gedit.desktop` and `/etc/gnome/defaults.list` respectively.

Answer (score 12):

Save this as `~/.local/share/applications/vim.desktop`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Vim Text Editor
Comment=Edit text files
Exec=vim %F
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Icon=vim
Categories=Utility;TextEditor;
StartupNotify=true
MimeType=text/plain;
```

Then in Nautilus right-click on a text file, choose "Properties" and go to "Open with". If vim isn't shown here click "Show other applications". Select vim and click "Set as default".

Answer (score 3):

The problem with the `vim.desktop` approach is that each time it will open a new terminal window, instead of using an existing vim instance. This is probably not what you want, but I don't think there's any way around it.

The next best thing is using `gvim`, which is a GUI app, instead of a terminal app.

Comment: I think by default gvim will also open a new instance.  There is a way around this, I think by using a gvim switch.  I used to have it open in a new tab with the existing gvim before I reinstalled Ubuntu.

Comment: _Is_ `gvim` a Gnome app? I think the 'g' stands for 'graphical', not 'Gnome'.

Comment: @voithos: Indeed, the 'g' doesn't stand for 'Gnome'. Corrected.

Answer (score 2):

Pure command line based method:

```
echo "[Desktop Entry]
Name=Vim Text Editor
Comment=Edit text files
Exec=vim %F
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Icon=vim
Categories=Utility;TextEditor;
StartupNotify=true
MimeType=text/plain;" > ~/.local/share/applications/vim.desktop
cp /etc/gnome/defaults.list ~/defaults.list.bak # backup
sudo sed -i "s/=gedit\.desktop/=vim\.desktop/" /etc/gnome/defaults.list
mkdir ~/.icons
wget -O ~/.icons/vim.png http://en.xn--icne-wqa.com/images/icones/1/4/vim.png # if you want an icon
```