# Missing applications in "Open With... Aplications" menu

Tags: context-menu

After installing certain applications I can't get them to show up under *Open With* from the right-click context menu when I right click on a file.
If I click on the *Other Application...* from the context menu and click on the *Show other applications* I can't find them on the list.
 Is there a way to manually add applications to this menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the application is not listed, once you click on Show Other Applications, then, an `.desktop` file needs to be created in `~/.local/share/applications`

To create that file, take a look at this [Post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/97683/how-can-i-change-the-default-text-editor-from-gedit-to-vim/97696#97696) to see an example on how its done.