# Problem setting VIM as standard text editor

Tags: vim, latex, nemo, file-association

I want to set vim (not gvim, not vi) as standard text editor. In the net there are the following suggestions to associate programs with file types.

1. use sudo update-alternatives --config editor [link](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Set_Vim_as_your_default_editor_for_Unix)
2. doing something with .desktop files [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/97683/how-can-i-change-the-default-text-editor-from-gedit-to-vim)
3. use mimeopen -d vim [link](http://ubuntugenius.wordpress.com/2012/06/18/ubuntu-fix-add-program-to-list-of-applications-in-open-with-when-right-clicking-files-in-nautilus/)

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and nemo as file manager. When I tried update-alternatives I got the following prompt:

```
 Selection    Path                Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/vim.gnome   60        auto mode
  1            /bin/ed             -100       manual mode
  2            /bin/nano            40        manual mode
* 3            /usr/bin/vim.basic   30        manual mode
  4            /usr/bin/vim.gnome   60        manual mode
  5            /usr/bin/vim.tiny    10        manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

Unfortunately nothing changed after I selected option 3. Then I tried the second method with the desktop-files. It works great for txt-files, but not for .tex files. Then I tried to associate .tex files via

```
mimeopen -d *.tex

Please choose a default application for files of type text/x-tex

1) vim  (vim-usercreated-1)
2) Texmaker  (texmaker)
3) SecureDownloadManager  (wine-extension-sdx)
4) notepad  (wine-extension-txt)
5) LibreOffice Writer  (libreoffice-writer)
6) gedit  (gedit)
7) Geany  (geany)
8) GVim  (gvim)
9) Other...
```

The prompt I answered simple with "vim" as you can see in the first item of the list. Since then everytime a .swp file is created after opening the .tex-file in nemo, without showing me anything of the vim terminal. So it is kind of running but it does not show up on screen. When I open the tex file with a command like xdg-open I get a warning "Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal".

On the net I could not find any more options to accomplish this file association. Please help me :)

Answer (score 3):

Nemo is not able to directly open a command line programme in the foreground. Therefore, the trick is to instruct Nemo to open a new terminal window and pass `vim` as an argument.

Open a Nemo window and right click on a `.tex` file. Then select ***Open With...*** and ***Other Application...***; in the window that shows up type the following in the ***Enter a custom command...*** box:

`gnome-terminal -x vim`

And click ***Add to list***. It should then look like this:

[image]

Then click ***OK***. Now double click on the `.tex` file, a new terminal should pop up running vim editing the file.