# How do I set the default file association in Ubuntu Nautilus to something that is not listed in the Open With tab?

Tags: nautilus, file-association

There used to be an option for adding unlisted commands, but it seems to be gone in Unity. Does anyone know how to do that now?

Comment: Switching to XFCE fixed the problem... :P

Answer (score 20, accepted):

one can use `mimeopen -d file` to use a custom application on the cli. Afterwards it will be the default application [even from the Nautilus].

> $ mimeopen -d file.txt
>
> Please choose a default application for files of type text/plain

```
      1) notepad  (wine-extension-txt)
      2) gedit  (gedit)
      3) GNU Emacs 23  (emacs23)
      4) Other...
```

> use application # 4
>
> use command: nano
>
> Opening "useful.txt" with nano  (text/plain)

There are other ways you can find [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69722/applications-missing-in-other-applications-list-how-to-change-default-applic)