# Using mimeopen to set default application outputs "Cancelled"

Tags: command-line, default-programs

I'm attempting to follow the steps [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/369967/how-do-i-set-the-default-file-association-in-ubuntu-13-10-nautilus-files-with-un) to change the the default application that opens a Blender file.

I input the command `mimeopen -dmime my_file.blend` and when prompted for the application, I input the path to a new version of Blender.  Note: I have used this method once to successfully associate .blend files with an older version of Blender, but I can't switch the association now.  It just outputs `cancelled`.

```
~/Desktop $ mimeopen -d my_file.blend
gtPlease choose a default application for files of type application/x-blender

1) home  (home-usercreated-1)
2) Other...

use application #/home/garrett/blender-2.69-2aeb492-linux-glibc211-x86_64/blender
Cancelled
~/Desktop $
```

I also tried using this method to change associations of .txt files to `/usr/bin/gedit` with the same result.

What's going wrong?  I'm on Ubuntu 13.10 and using mimeopen 0.15 (the default).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see [from mimeopen's source](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/PARDUS/File-MimeInfo-0.15/mimeopen) (I searched for "Cancelled"), it's expecting a number.

If you want to specify an application, in your case, specify 2 (for "Other...") and *then* specify the command.