# How disassociate VLC from video/audio files

Tags: lubuntu, vlc, lxde, openbox, file-association

I'm using `Lubuntu 14.04` and I have `VLC` & `mplayer` and `audious`.
I want to keep `VLC` but use `mplayer` & `audious` as default players.
While I change default player for video & audio player from `lxsession-default-apps` and also change default application in `Open With` section of file properties but it still opens all video & audio files with VLC

How Can I Disassociate file types from VLC and set them to another application in LXDE/OpenBox/PCManFM ?

Comment: Possible duplicate? : http://askubuntu.com/questions/369967/how-do-i-set-the-default-file-association-in-ubuntu-nautilus-to-something-that-i

Comment: @IzznogooooD: I'm on Lubuntu which  means I use LXDE/OpenBox/PCManFM ; There is no Nautilus here!

Comment: Forget about Nautilus, did you try the solution?

Comment: @IzznogooooD: Yes; there is no `mimeopen` here neither; I want to find the way VLC is locked itself as verrrry (!!) default application in my current config;

Comment: The program 'mimeopen' is not installed by default in Lubuntu 14.04. You can install it by typing:
`sudo apt-get install libfile-mimeinfo-perl`.

Comment: @DKBose: yes and I did so; and it has no effect;

Comment: Local changes should be able to be manipulated in the file `$HOME/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`. Open it with your favourite text editor and have a look. Back up before altering :)