# eeschema.html open by wrong App - KompoZer

Tags: documentation, html, kompozer

This may not be a problem with *KiCad* or even the Documents, but I need a place to start. When using the help menu to open the *Eeschema* or *KiCad* Manuals they open in the editor *KompoZer* that had been installed long before either *Eeschema* or *KiCad*. In example `/usr/share/doc/kicad/help/en/eeschema.html` will open in the *KompoZer* HTML editor. The Properties of **eeschema.html** are set to open FireFox web browser according to nautilus file manager. Doing a Google search on the problem only results in how to install *KompoZer* a program left over from Ubuntu 12.04 LTS but I keep in 14.04.5 as it is easy to use. I don't believe  *KompoZer* is any longer supported, so I need to figure out how to troubleshoot this problem. If someone could get me started this would be great!
Thanks James

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the right answer, but is seems to work. I am hoping by running the command in only the directory `/usr/share/doc/kicad/help/en` this will not effect the root drive or path. Anyway the answer was found as the question
"[How do I set the default file association in Ubuntu Nautilus to something that is not listed in the Open With tab](https://askubuntu.com/questions/369967/how-do-i-set-the-default-file-association-in-ubuntu-nautilus-to-something-that-i)?" in Ask Ubuntu by [souravc](https://askubuntu.com/users/127327/souravc).

The command I ended up using was `/usr/share/doc/kicad/help/en$ mimeopen -d *.html` and my choice was the generic ubuntu Browser selection form the selections (not all enumerated)

```
Please choose a default application for files of type text/html

1) Browser  (webbrowser-app)
2) winebrowser  (wine-extension-htm)
3) Luakit  (luakit)
4) KompoZer  (kompozer)
5) Opera  (opera)
6) Firefox ESR  (firefox-esr)
7) Firefox Web Browser  (firefox)
8) Google Chrome  (google-chrome)
9) Geany  (geany)
```

I do not know however what the following generated messages mean or if it is a concern? But the Documents seem to no longer open in *KopoZer* web page editor!
Perhaps someone could enlighten me about the latter as I have much to learn:-)

`use application #1
Opening "cvpcb.html", "eeschema.html", "gerbview.html", "getting_started_in_kicad.html", "gui_translation_howto.html", "idf_exporter.html", "kicad.html", "pcbnew.html", "pl_editor.html", "plugins.html" with Browser  (text/html)
[0922/084031.493187:ERROR:child_thread_impl.cc(762)] Request for unknown Channel-associated interface: ui::mojom::GpuMain
OxideQQuickWebView: loadingChanged is deprecated. Please connect loadEvent if you want load event notifications, or loadingStateChanged if you want to detect changes to the loading property 
OxideQQuickWebContext: userAgentOverrideDelegate is deprecated. Please use userAgentOverrides instead 
Loaded 1 UA override(s) from file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/Ubuntu/Components/Extras/Browser/ua-overrides-desktop.js
OxideQQuickWebView: canGoForward is deprecated. Please use the API provided by OxideQQuickNavigationHistory instead 
OxideQQuickWebView: canGoBack is deprecated. Please use the API provided by OxideQQuickNavigationHistory instead 
[0922/084031.977250:ERROR:child_thread_impl.cc(762)] Request for unknown Channel-associated interface: ui::mojom::GpuMain
OxideQQuickWebView: loadingChanged is deprecated. Please connect loadEvent if you want load event notifications, or loadingStateChanged if you want to detect changes to the loading property 
OxideQQuickWebContext: userAgentOverrideDelegate is deprecated. Please use userAgentOverrides instead 
Loaded 1 UA override(s) from file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/Ubuntu/Components/Extras/Browser/ua-overrides-desktop.js
[0922/084032.145653:ERROR:child_thread_impl.cc(762)] Request for unknown Channel-associated interface: ui::mojom::GpuMain
OxideQQuickWebView: loadingChanged is deprecated. Please connect loadEvent if you want load event notifications, or loadingStateChanged if you want to detect changes to the loading property 
OxideQQuickWebContext: userAgentOverrideDelegate is deprecated. Please use userAgentOverrides instead 
Loaded 1 UA override(s) from file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/Ubuntu/Components/Extras/Browser/ua-overrides-desktop.js
OxideQQuickWebView: canGoForward is deprecated. Please use the API provided by OxideQQuickNavigationHistory instead 
OxideQQuickWebView: canGoBack is deprecated. Please use the API provided by OxideQQuickNavigationHistory instead 
OxideQQuickWebView: canGoForward is deprecated. Please use the API provided by OxideQQuickNavigationHistory instead 
OxideQQuickWebView: canGoBack is deprecated. Please use the API provided by OxideQQuickNavigationHistory instead 
[0922/084032.478951:ERROR:child_thread_impl.cc(762)] Request for unknown Channel-associated interface: ui::mojom::GpuMain
[0922/084032.481142:ERROR:child_thread_impl.cc(762)] Request for unknown Channel-associated interface: ui::mojom::GpuMain
OxideQQuickWebView: loadingChanged is deprecated. Please connect loadEvent if you want load event notifications, or loadingStateChanged if you want to detect changes to the loading property 
OxideQQuickWebContext: userAgentOverrideDelegate is deprecated. Please use userAgentOverrides instead 
OxideQQuickWebView: loadingChanged is deprecated. Please connect loadEvent if you want load event notifications, or loadingStateChanged if you want to detect changes to the loading property 
OxideQQuickWebContext: userAgentOverrideDelegate is deprecated. Please use userAgentOverrides instead 
Loaded 1 UA override(s) from file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/Ubuntu/Components/Extras/Browser/ua-overrides-desktop.js
Loaded 1 UA override(s) from file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/Ubuntu/Components/Extras/Browser/ua-overrides-desktop.js
[0922/084032.578491:ERROR:layer_tree_host_impl.cc(2190)] Forcing zero-copy tile initialization as worker context is missing
OxideQQuickWebView: canGoForward is deprecated. Please use the API provided by OxideQQuickNavigationHistory instead 
OxideQQuickWebView: canGoBack is deprecated. Please use the API provided by OxideQQuickNavigationHistory instead 
OxideQQuickWebView: canGoForward is deprecated. Please use the API provided by OxideQQuickNavigationHistory instead 
OxideQQuickWebView: canGoBack is deprecated. Please use the API provided by OxideQQuickNavigationHistory instead 
[0922/084032.658138:ERROR:child_thread_impl.cc(762)] Request for unknown Channel-associated interface: ui::mojom::GpuMain
OxideQQuickWebView: loadingChanged is deprecated. Please connect loadEvent if you want load event notifications, or loadingStateChanged if you want to detect changes to the loading property 
OxideQQuickWebContext: userAgentOverrideDelegate is deprecated. Please use userAgentOverrides instead 
Loaded 1 UA override(s) from file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/Ubuntu/Components/Extras/Browser/ua-overrides-desktop.js
[0922/084032.732053:ERROR:layer_tree_host_impl.cc(2190)] Forcing zero-copy tile initialization as worker context is missing
OxideQQuickWebView: canGoForward is deprecated. Please use the API provided by OxideQQuickNavigationHistory instead 
OxideQQuickWebView: canGoBack is deprecated. Please use the API provided by OxideQQuickNavigationHistory instead 
[0922/084032.862368:ERROR:child_thread_impl.cc(762)] Request for unknown Channel-associated interface: ui::mojom::GpuMain
OxideQQuickWebView: loadingChanged is deprecated. Please connect loadEvent if you want load event notifications, or loadingStateChanged if you want to detect changes to the loading property 
OxideQQuickWebContext: userAgentOverrideDelegate is deprecated. Please use userAgentOverrides instead 
Loaded 1 UA override(s) from file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/Ubuntu/Components/Extras/Browser/ua-overrides-desktop.js
OxideQQuickWebView: canGoForward is deprecated. Please use the API provided by OxideQQuickNavigationHistory instead 
OxideQQuickWebView: canGoBack is deprecated. Please use the API provided by OxideQQuickNavigationHistory instead 
[0922/084033.193566:ERROR:layer_tree_host_impl.cc(2190)] Forcing zero-copy tile initialization as worker context is missing
[0922/084033.193805:ERROR:layer_tree_host_impl.cc(2190)] Forcing zero-copy tile initialization as worker context is missing
[0922/084033.380643:ERROR:child_thread_impl.cc(762)] Request for unknown Channel-associated interface: ui::mojom::GpuMain
OxideQQuickWebView: loadingChanged is deprecated. Please connect loadEvent if you want load event notifications, or loadingStateChanged if you want to detect changes to the loading property 
OxideQQuickWebContext: userAgentOverrideDelegate is deprecated. Please use userAgentOverrides instead 
Loaded 1 UA override(s) from file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/Ubuntu/Components/Extras/Browser/ua-overrides-desktop.js
[0922/084033.402729:ERROR:child_thread_impl.cc(762)] Request for unknown Channel-associated interface: ui::mojom::GpuMain
OxideQQuickWebView: loadingChanged is deprecated. Please connect loadEvent if you want load event notifications, or loadingStateChanged if you want to detect changes to the loading property 
OxideQQuickWebContext: userAgentOverrideDelegate is deprecated. Please use userAgentOverrides instead 
Loaded 1 UA override(s) from file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/Ubuntu/Components/Extras/Browser/ua-overrides-desktop.js
[0922/084033.411169:ERROR:child_thread_impl.cc(762)] Request for unknown Channel-associated interface: ui::mojom::GpuMain
OxideQQuickWebView: loadingChanged is deprecated. Please connect loadEvent if you want load event notifications, or loadingStateChanged if you want to detect changes to the loading property 
OxideQQuickWebContext: userAgentOverrideDelegate is deprecated. Please use userAgentOverrides instead 
Loaded 1 UA override(s) from file:///usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/Ubuntu/Components/Extras/Browser/ua-overrides-desktop.js
[0922/084033.523098:ERROR:layer_tree_host_impl.cc(2190)] Forcing zero-copy tile initialization as worker context is missing
[0922/084033.564325:ERROR:layer_tree_host_impl.cc(2190)] Forcing zero-copy tile initialization as worker context is missing
[0922/084033.600776:ERROR:layer_tree_host_impl.cc(2190)] Forcing zero-copy tile initialization as worker context is missing
OxideQQuickWebView: canGoForward is deprecated. Please use the API provided by OxideQQuickNavigationHistory instead 
OxideQQuickWebView: canGoBack is deprecated. Please use the API provided by OxideQQuickNavigationHistory instead 
OxideQQuickWebView: canGoForward is deprecated. Please use the API provided by OxideQQuickNavigationHistory instead 
OxideQQuickWebView: canGoBack is deprecated. Please use the API provided by OxideQQuickNavigationHistory instead 
OxideQQuickWebView: canGoForward is deprecated. Please use the API provided by OxideQQuickNavigationHistory instead 
OxideQQuickWebView: canGoBack is deprecated. Please use the API provided by OxideQQuickNavigationHistory instead 
[0922/084034.268586:ERROR:layer_tree_host_impl.cc(2190)] Forcing zero-copy tile initialization as worker context is missing
[0922/084034.401553:ERROR:layer_tree_host_impl.cc(2190)] Forcing zero-copy tile initialization as worker context is missing
[0922/084035.393201:ERROR:layer_tree_host_impl.cc(2190)] Forcing zero-copy tile initialization as worker context is missing`